# select specific element using jQuery attr() Method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, attr

If I have 5 images on a page, they are all the exact same image, as seen below

```
<body>
<img src="http://httpJunkie.com/1st/jQ02/orangeCat.jpg" >
<img src="http://httpJunkie.com/1st/jQ02/orangeCat.jpg" >
<img src="http://httpJunkie.com/1st/jQ02/orangeCat.jpg" >
<img src="http://httpJunkie.com/1st/jQ02/orangeCat.jpg" >
<img src="http://httpJunkie.com/1st/jQ02/orangeCat.jpg" >
</body>
```

I have access to them only using JavaScript and I need to use jQuery to modify the *height* of each one. Let's say the first one needs to be `10px x 10px` and and each consecutive image needs to be scaled up by `10px`. I know I can select the first one using:

```
$("body img:first").attr({
    width: 10,
   height: 10,
});
```

and the last one by using

```
$("body img:last").attr({
    width: 60,
    height: 60,
});
```

My primary question is how can I select on image number 3 by using the .attr() method, similar to the code above

I tried using nth-child and it didn't work.

**P.S: I know I can use a loop to change them all at once?**

Comment: [eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq/), [:eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/), [gt](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/), [lt](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/), [nth-child](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/), [nth-of-type](http://api.jquery.com/nth-of-type-selector/), [nth-last-child](http://api.jquery.com/nth-last-child-selector/). -> [**https://learn.jquery.com/**](https://learn.jquery.com/)

Comment: I came here from the learning center as I was having a problem using n-th child. I still cannot get the nth child example to work. But the eq() example is working fine. What is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `:eq` selector, or `eq()` method:

```
$("body img:eq(3)").attr({
   width: 10,
   height: 10,
});

$("body img").eq(3).attr({
   width: 10,
   height: 10,
});
```

Both of the above have the same result.

Comment: Is there a reason why my attempts at using nth child are not working but eq() works fine? Is one better than the other? I know that eq() creates a new object each time I use it to select, does that mean if I loo through them it may cause more overhead behind the scenes than using nth child?

Comment: No, looping over a selector is always the same overhead, no matter what the selector is. Without seeing your `nth-child` code it's hard to say what the problem is, but the API has all the info you would ever need: http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use index to set the varying height width instead of individually setting them. use:

```
$("body img").each(function(i){
 $(this).attr({
  width: 10*(i+1),
  height:10*(i+1)
});});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Q5kM3/)**

[image]

Comment: This gives me what I need for the looping, now that I can target individual items, I would have been able to write a loop. But I appreciate you taking the time to answer and that is why I 1up'd your answer. But Rory answered the primary question first so I checked his as correct. I am writing a tutorial and was writing about the attr() method. when my attempts to use nth child failed I posed the question here. Again I really appreciate the working demo.  HIGH FIVE!

Comment: @EricB: glad it helps eric... :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use eq() function from jquery.

Here are more details http://api.jquery.com/eq/

Comment: Link-only answers aren't enough. Please provide a summary of the link. You may also want to show an example.

Comment: actually, this link did help, working demos have already been provided so this answer does provide me help to my answer in conjunction with the other answers I think it's just fine.